# how to solve "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found."

Tags: android, api, android-networking, androidhttpclient, android-network-security-config

I am new to Networking, I got this error when i was trying get data from `newsapi.org` error: `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.`. I looked over some answers, but everything just bounced out of my head. I tried to search for "public certification" in newsapi.org also but i dint find anything. Please anyone help me out, who can i find the certification, and any source or links about the Trust anchor and basics.

Thank you.